# Gibt es das Wort "das Tunnell"?

Tags: dialect

Im Fränkischen höre ich öfter neben dem Wort "der Tunnel" auch die Variante "das Tunnel". Die zweite Silbe ist betont, phonetisch könnte man "Tunnell" schreiben.

Im Gegensatz zu "der Tunnel", das ganz verschiedene Dinge bezeichnen kann, wird "das Tunnell" eigentlich nur für physische, von Menschen gebaute Tunnel gebraucht, die der Durchfahrt dienen.

Menschen aus anderen Gegenden kennen diesen Gebrauch oft nicht. Duden und Wiktionary offenbar auch nicht. Es gibt aber mindestens ein Schnaderhüpfl, in dem diese Aussprache verwendet wird:

> Drunt' in den Alpen, da gibt's a Tunnel
>   Wennst' nei fährst wird's dunkel, wennst' naus fährst wird's hell

Ist dieser Gebrauch irgendwo dokumentiert? Wie weit ist er verbreitet?

Comment: Ich kenne auch beides (aus dem Schwabenlande).

Comment: Hier kannst du mehr über die verschiedenen Betonungen erfahren.http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_4/f23a-c/index.html

Comment: Was bitte ist ein Schnaderhüpfl? Ein fränkischer Brozonkenwilzt?

Comment: @user unknown - http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schnaderhuepferl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich nehme an, dass Neutrum und eine volltonige zweite Silbe zumindest in Österreich und der Schweiz überall verbreitet ist, ferner auch im Süddeutschen ursprünglich verbreitet waren. Somit könnte wohl die Aussprache mit unbetonter zweiter Silbe ([ˈtʰʊnl]) als astreiner Teutonismus gelten, da sie ausserhalb Deutschlands nicht auftritt, und genauer als eine (mittel- und?) norddeutsche Eigenheit.

Spass beiseite: Ich kann bezeugen, dass Neutrum und Aussprache mit volltoniger zweiter Silbe in der Schweiz verbreitet ist – allerdings nicht mit Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe, sondern auf der ersten. Trotzdem sind beide Silben volltonig, die Aussprache wäre also ungefähr [ts ˈtunælː] (übrigens *nicht* mit langem [nː]!). In der Standardsprache dringt allerdings die nördliche Aussprache [ˈtʰʊnl] immer weiter vor (ähnlich wie andere nördliche Eigenarten wie *«die* E-Mail», «das Frühstück» oder «die Treppe»). In der gewöhnlichen Umgangssprache – also im schweizerdeutschen Dialekt – ist jedoch die Anfangsbetonung normal, ähnlich wie auch in Wörtern wie *Káffee, Hótel, Wággon, Bíllet, Kárton, Bálkon, Bǘro, Pórtemonnaie, Gárage, Pápagei* usw., ferner auch in Abkürzungen wie CD, WC, VW, USA, usw. Leider geht die Analyse [Betonung « atlas-alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f23a-c/) darauf überhaupt nicht auf die Betonung ein (es ist auch nicht ihr Thema) – dafür aber wenigstens die Karte [Balkon, Karton (Aussprache) « atlas-alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f9ab/).

Comment: Wenn du jetzt anfängst, lange und kurze Konsonanten zu unterscheiden, schicken wir dich nach Finnland!

Comment: Neinein, ich bleibe in der Schweiz – der Vergleich mit dem Finnischen ist allerdings durchaus nicht abwegig. Für die Analyse von schweizerdeutschen Fortes als lang und Lenes als kurz vgl. den knappen Überblick auf S. 244 f. in [Zurich German](http://www.uta.edu/faculty/cmfitz/swnal/projects/CoLang/courses/Transcription/Fleischer_and_Schmidt.pdf) sowie die weiterführende Literatur. Und irgendwoher kommen die zahlreichen Doppelkonsonanten in unserer Rechtschreibung ja auch – nicht dass die Rechtschreibung aus dem Schweizerdeutschen käme, aber aus einer älteren Sprachstufe mit langen Konsonanten.

Comment: Ich dachte, die Doppelkonsonanten hätte mal jemand eingeführt, um kurze Vokale zu markieren. Das habe ich jedenfalls fürs Englische mal so gehört, wenn auch in dem eigentlich nicht so tollen Podcast „History of English“. Das mit dem Finnischen habe ich eingeworfen, weil ein Freund von mir beklagt hat, dass sie darin lange und kurze Konsonanten tatsächlich unterscheiden.

Comment: @CarstenS: Für die älteren Sprachstufen (Altenglisch, Alt- und Mittelhochdeutsch) geht die Forschung von echten langen Konsonanten aus. Recht eigentlich ist dies auch eine logische Voraussetzung für den Gebrauch von Doppelkonsonanten für die Markierung von kurzen Vokalen: Damit man überhaupt auf eine solche Idee kommt, müssen Doppelkonsonanten schon vorher in der Schrift vorhanden sein, und zwar am häufigsten vor kuzen Vokalen.

Comment: @Carsten - Nachfolgende Konsonanten zweimal zu schreiben, um die Kürze des vorhergehenden Vokals zu signalisieren, ist ja eigentlich eine, Verzeihung, völlig bescheuerte Methode. Wer sich so etwas ausgedacht hat... brrr! Da lobt man sich die Ungarn und die Finnen, die für lange Vokale schlicht die Vokale markieren (Akzent oder Verdopplung).

Comment: In der Podcastfolge ging es, wenn ich mich recht erinnere, ums [Ormulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ormulum).

Answer (score 9):

Duden kennt nur die hochdeutsche Version *der Tunnel* als Maskulinum. Schaut man bei DWDS nach, findet man dort

> Nebenform österreichisch, schweizerisch Tunell · Substantiv (Neutrum) · Genitiv Singular: Tunells · Nominativ Plural: Tunelle

(also auch mit einer anderen Pluralbildung).

Im schwäbischen Dialekt heißt es, wie schon erwähnt wurde, ebenfalls *das Tunell* und das auch noch im Gegensatz zum hochdeutschen Wort mit Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe.

Comment: Ich kann mich da nur anschließen. In Österreich, woher ich komme, kennt man beide Formen.

Comment: Mein Duden (Universalwörterbuch) kennt auch: *Tu|nell, das; s, -e (süddeutsch, österreichisch): --> Tunnel*

Answer (score 1):

### Betonung

Die Version, bei der die zweite Silbe betont ist, ist laut [Atlas der Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f23a-c/) in Südtirol sogar einzige gebräuchliche Version:

[image]

In Österreich sind beide Versionen in Verwendung, und in Deutschland wird die hinten betonte Version vereinzelt verwendet.

---

### Geschlecht

Auch das Geschlecht dieses Wortes wurde im [Atlas der Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/) erhoben:

[image]

Es fällt auf, dass die regionale Verteilung des Geschlechts von der regionalen Verteilung der Betonung unabhängig ist. Denn die sächliche Version (das Tunnel) findet man (bis auf vereinzelte Ausnahmen) in der Schweiz.

Comment: Naja, da die zweite Abfrage die Betonung nicht mitliefert, kämen "bilinguale" Sprecher wie ich in Bedrängnis - natürlich heißt es *der* Túnnel in der Hochsprache, aber *das* Tunnél im Dialekt - die Version mit 2. 'l' liest man normalerweise nicht, man hört sie nur.